# Closed form of Gaussian-like summation?

Tags: summation

I want to evaluate 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{-n^2}$$

My attempt is to evaluate
$$\oint_{|z|=\infty}\pi\cot(\pi z)e^{-z^2}dz$$
and prove the circular integral tends to zero.

Unfortunately, this is clearly not the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use euler mac laurin formula :D there is no close formula for your sum though

Comment: This sum is related with Theta Functions.